# Trying to perform Blob storage and adding the form data to data store Preflight Error

Tags: java, angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Using Google Appengine Endpoints
Created A servlet to help handle form post data for registration and uploading of a logo image file. 
The way it works is that it first of all goes to a blob servlet which will then  return a link like this

`url:` http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/ag1oZXJjdWxlcy0yMDE1ciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgICAqAkM

for my form post to redirect to the url generated by the blob servlet, The JUNIT test is working well, But when i try to accept from my frontend built with angular i get the first response from the blob servlet which our URL now processing our form post to that url returns this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/ag1oZXJjdWxlcy0yMDE1ciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgICAqAkM.<br> 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' <br>    header is present on the requested resource.    <br>    Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

been battling with this for days , what seems to be the problem with **preflight**

See the front end (from localhost:9000) code

```
//send link to blob_store 
  /**
  blob_servlet_url is the link to our blob_servlet which is something like this localhost:8080/blob_servlet
  */
$http.get(blob_servlet_url)
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     //move our form data to server now
    uploadUrl=data; //return the url to forward form data
    console.log("Url:- "+data);
     var formData = {};

    $http({url:uploadUrl,method:'POST',data:formData}).then(
      function (resp) {
      //success
        console.log(resp);
    },
      function (reason) {
      //error 
      });


  })
  .error(function (data, status, header, config) {

  });
```

Comment: Facing the same issue .Still troubleshooting .

Comment: setting the content-type to undefined would make javascript pass the header data As it is , and over writing the default angular $httpProvider header configurations. [Angular $http Documentation][1]


  [1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

    $http({url:url,method:"POST", headers:{'Content-Type':undefined}).then(success,failure);

Answer (score 0):

setting the content-type to undefined would make javascript pass the header data As it is , and over writing the default angular $httpProvider header configurations. [Angular $http Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http({url:url,method:"POST", headers:{'Content-Type':undefined}).then(success,failure); Theophiluses answer is correct
```